# Errors moving from PHP4 to server with PHP5

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following 3 errors moving my website from PHP 4 to a server with PHP 5. Can anyone help me please?

> Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid
>   MySQL-Link resource in /home/xxxxx /index.php on line 37

```
mysql_select_db($conn, "yourmil_content");
```

---

> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link
>   resource in/home/xxxxxx/index.php on line 247

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
```

---

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in/home/xxxxx/index.php on line 248

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: Try echoing `mysql_error()` after you set `$conn` and post that please

Comment: Did you Google those error messages? There's bound to be thousands.

Comment: `$conn` is not being set, your database connection is failing.

Answer (score 0):

At first (Assumed `$conn` is a valid connection)

```
$conn = mysql_connect('host_name', 'user_name', 'mysql_password');
```

Then

```
mysql_select_db($conn, "yourmil_content");
```

Should be

```
mysql_select_db("yourmil_content", $conn);
```

You supplied arguments in wrong order and that's why `Database` is not selected according to this error

> Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid
> MySQL-Link resource in /home/xxxxx /index.php on line 37

Since, database is not selected, rest of the things are not going to work. Check  [mysql_select_db](https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db) and also, notice the `deprecated` warning.